# dataframe from a url for further analysis(mean,median etc) in python pandas doesnt present proper answer but not suceeded

Tags: jupyter-notebook

i am trying to fetch data from a URL(git hub) for further analysis(mean ,average ,percentage , ratio etc) but this code is not properly working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/u.user')
df = pd.DataFrame([a.split('|') for a in res.text.split('\n')])
df.columns = df.values[0]
df.drop([df.index[0],df.index[df.shape[0]-1]],inplace=True)
print(df['age'].astype(int).mean())
```

Output:
`34.05196182396607`

Dataframe:

[image]

Comment: Thanx for your reply..further with this code  df.age.mean() is not working error: no age object found

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: @uma, if this answer solves your question, please accept the answer